# Parent selector on external css broken

Tags: html, css

The below code works but when I have the same code in an external stylesheet it will not style the box. Just wondering why or how I can fix it?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="style" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
     
   <style>#boxes .box{
        height: 20px;
        border: 2px solid red;
        background-color: red;
    } 
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="boxes">
        <div class="box">Box</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Heres is the code in the external CSS

```
#boxes .box{
    height: 20px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: in wich folder is your html and in wich folder is the css? if for example the css is one folder heigher simply add ../style.css if it is two folders heigher add ../../style.css but I need to know where you put the css file and where you put the html file. to be able to help you.

Comment: they are in the same folder

Comment: In that case your code is good I tried it on my computer and it works are you sure the css file is really named "style.css" and not "style.css.txt" or "styles.css"

Comment: Yep it is all named correctly, im very confused

Comment: If it where named correctly and in the same folder it would work. What you could try is make a folder on you desktop call it "site"  in the folder site add the file "index.html" and "style.css" and try again. Otherwise you could download it here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O_u5c1LeawUOfoImRNf31zZHd4eH1iCm/view?usp=sharing and extract to your computer on desktop.

Comment: Try rel=stylesheet instead of style